# Angular Profile service with property getter / setters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to have a singleton Angular service with getters and setters with logic?  I was given the following snippet and asked to mimic it in an Angular service.  It may sound simple but I'm losing my mind:

```
public class Profile 
{
    private AuthSvc _auth = new AuthSvc();

    private string _userId = null;
    private string _displayName = null;

    public string UserId
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_userId != null) { return _userId; }
            _userId = AuthSvc.getUserId();
            return _userId; 
        }
    }
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_displayName != null) { return _displayName; }
            if (_userId == null) { return null; }
            _displayName = AuthSvc.getDisplayName(_userId);
            return _displayName; 
        }
        set (string value) {
            if (value == null && value.trim().length < 1) { return; }
            if (_displayName != null && _displayName == value.trim()) { return; }
            _displayName = value.trim();
            AuthSvc.setDisplayName(_userId, _displayName); 
        }
    }

}
```

My failed attempt before I started crying:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .service('Profile', ProfileService);

    ProfileService.$inject = ['common', 'dataService'];
    function ProfileService (common, dataService) {

        var userInfo = {
            id   : '',
            name : ''
        };

        var service = {
            id : $get getUserId(),
            name : $get getUserId(), $set(value, setUserId);
        };

        return service;
        /////////////////////////

        function getUserId () {
            if (!userInfo.id) { userInfo.id = common.getUserId(); }
            return userInfo.id;
        }

        function setName (value) {

        }

        function getName () {
            if (userInfo.name) { return userInfo.name; }
            var userId = getUserId();
            if (!userId) { return ''; }
            dataService.users.getDisplayName(userId).then(function(name){

            });
        }

    }

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written the `service` as a `factory`.

An angular `service` is a constructor that uses `this` for all properties and a `factory` is a function that returns an object

You should be fine switching the component from `service` to `factory`

```
angular
    .module('myapp')
    .factory('Profile', ProfileService);
```

But you should also be passing function and object variable references to the returned object also

Along the lines of:

```
  var service = {
        userInfo  : userInfo ,
        getUserId :  getUserId,
        getName : getName 
    };
  // or 
  service.myfunc = someNamedFunction;
```

Alternatively keeping it as as service  switch all variables to be members of `this`

Comment: Are you sure?  Syntactically it looks completely wrong.  If I return `service` then my `userInfo` object is lost.  And if I store `userInfo` in the `service` object then the functions won't be able to access it later.

Comment: Here's a working factory example http://plnkr.co/edit/5pURfBAb7ELOgP9064Cc?p=preview

Comment: @G.Deward you are storing a reference to that object...and yes the functions have access to anything in your factory scope

Comment: Yes, THIS makes sense... having an action, like `getRecipes()` trigger the loading of the `master_recipes`.  The part I'm losing my mind on is the trigger taking place when someone calls the property.  For example, loading the recipes the first time someone invokes: `$scope.favorites = recipes.favorites'

Comment: It's prototypical inheritance. Assign any number of variables to an array or object and they are all referencing the same array/object. Thus changing a property using any of those variables changes the main object

Comment: Really?  So there ARE reference value types in JavaScript!?!?!  Ugh.

Comment: absolutely! That's the whole foundation of the way angular works

Answer (score 0):

Actually service is just a plain `object` and you can use `Object.defineProperty` on it. I use `factory` syntax.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('mymodule', [])
        .factory('myService', function () {
            var service = {};
            var userInfo = {
                 id   : '',
                 name : ''
            };
            serivce.getUserInfo = function(){ return userInfo;};

            var myPropertyPrivateVal;
            Object.defineProperty(service, 'myProperty', {
                get: function () { return myPropertyPrivateVal; },
                set: function(value) { myPropertyPrivateVal = value; }
            });

            return service;
        });
})();
```

And you are good to go :)

All the dirrefece when you use `service` syntax is that you use `this` instead of an object literal `var service = {};`

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('mymodule', [])
        .service('myService', function () {
                var userInfo = {id : '', name : '' };
                this.getUserInfo = function(){ return userInfo;};

                var myPropertyPrivateVal;  
                Object.defineProperty(this, 'myProperty', {
                    get: function () { return myPropertyPrivateVal; },
                    set: function(value) { myPropertyPrivateVal = value; }
                });
        });
})();
```

Comment: Interesting.  But, where is the local `userInfo` data?  It's supposed to be stored locally so the functions can check it upon the `get` or `set`.

Comment: Gotcha.  So the getter and setter of `myProperty` would just call `userInfo.id` to pull that value?

Comment: Actually i do not intend to do your job and just give you a syntax you can use to solve your problem. hope this helps